# App crash is not uploading info into StoreConnect or Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crashlytics

I have an app on AppStore that it is crashing on **SOME** iOS16 devices.
Unfortunately on my device with iOS16 it is not.
But on iOS16 devices from BrowserStack it is (TestFlight version of the App).

The craziest thing is that no crash report is uploaded into crashlytics (I have several other logs on this tool so it is working. User is relaunching the app.), if I check on AppStoreConnect on the Crashes section I see a row for the crash with my comments but I don't see the "Open in Xcode button.

So I decided to NSLog every "begin" and "end" of methods. I found the app crash on an init method, without even printing the "begin" log... the init where it crash is similar to this...

```
MyClass { 
    private var myVN: MyVM 

    init() { 
        NSLog("++ MyClass.init") 
        myVM = MyVM()
        bla bla bla 
        NSLOG("-- MyClass.init") 
    } 
}

MyVM { 
    privar other = OtherClass() 

    init() { 
        NSLog("++ MyVM.init") 
        other.doSomething()
        bla bla bla 
        NSLOG("-- MyVM.init") 
    } 
}
```

What I see on the BrowserStack console logs is only the "++ MyClass.init" but not the "++ MyVM.init".

What might be going on here?

Regards.

Comment: what was the crash? also why `NSLog` and not `os_log`. I mean is it because `os_log` didn't work for you? if so, that could be another symptom of the same issue

Comment: Can you post your crash log? Maybe on pastebin?

Comment: Can you please reach out to Browserstack support via our contact us page by sharing all the required information for better understanding and debugging? Thanks

Comment: Do you know if these crashes happen early in the startup process? Or if they are related to out of memory issues? or the OS closing the app?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your time and patient.
We have moved to another tasks, but we sill back with this issue at some point and will add more details. Thanks.

Comment: Hi all, 

After some code reviews, debugging and turning on the main thread checker we found that there was ui updates on a non main thread. This undefined behavior explains why on my simulator and device was running ok and why on other devices (ie Browser stack or other users devices) was crashing.

Thanks.